# Unknown server tag when using visual webpart in masterpage in sharpoint 2010

Tags: visual-web-part, register

This is just a basic question.

I have a solution say "My.Solution".In this I have a project say "My.Project". I added a visual webpart say "Menu". The namespace of the webpart is like My.Project.Menu. I checked the properties of this control and saw that the Safe Control entries are added by VS2010. I added this to a feature scoped at Site level and deployed the project. I activated the feature and edited the masterpage. I then registered the assembly as

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="nav" Namespace="My.Project.Menu" Assembly="My.Solution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87a45275f2ea36e3" %>
```

and called the webpart in the page as

```
<nav:My.Project.Menu runat="server" id="TopNavigationMenu" />
```

But when I save the page and refresh it in browser, I get the error,

```
 Unknown server tag 'nav:My.Project.Menu'
```

So for the sake of testing,

I changed the namespace of the visual webpart from My.Project.Menu to just Menu in all the files.Now I registed the assembly in masterpage as

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="nav" Namespace="Menu" Assembly="My.Solution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87a45275f2ea36e3" %>
```

and called the webpart in the page as

```
<nav:Menu runat="server" id="TopNavigationMenu" />
```

and this time it works.

I have tried this out several times in different solutions. When webpart is called with the namespace is nav:My.Project.Menu, it does not work, but when it is called with the namespace nav:Menu, it works.Can't visual studio take the entire namespace when it is called/registered in the webpage?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I have to use the class name when adding the reference instead of referring the namespace after the tagname. i.e. If my namespace was My.Project.Menu and if my classname(not filename) of webpart was NavMenu, then I will have to use

    <nav:NavMenu.....

instead of

    <nav:My.Project.Menu

Comment: You should answer your own question since you figured it out :)